# Runtime static_cast for Exceptions

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there any way to afford `static_cast`'s capabilities in `dynamic_cast` or in the RTTI used in the exception model?

Basically, I'd like to be able to get this to work:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

short a = 2;

void foo()
{
    throw a;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        foo();
    }
    catch (int i) // automatically used `static_cast<int>(short a)`
                  // or at least automatically does integer promotion
    {
        std::cout << *i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ignoring the exception part. Treating a `short*` as an `int*` is Undefined Behavior as it violates the strict aliasing rules. Perhaps try and explain what is it that you are trying to do and why.

Comment: canonical way of catching exceptions is
`} catch (const Exception& ex) {`
keep this rule

Comment: @bolov I'd like the catch to automatically promote the `short` to an `int`. I've changed it from a pointer for clarity's sake.

Comment: @j5w sorry, but what you want can't be done. You have to catch exactly what you throw, there is no promotion performed. If you throw a `short`, you have to catch a `short`. The only exception (no pun) to that rule is throwing a polymorphic type and catching it by (reference/pointer to) a base type.  `short` and `int` are not polymorphic.

Comment: is there any particular reason why you want this? The usual way is to use polymorphism to catch multiple types with one type.